# Replace URLs in text with HTML links

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace, linkify

Here is a design though: For example is I put a link such as

> http://example.com

in **textarea**. How do I get PHP to detect it’s a `http://` link and then print it as

```
print "<a href='http://www.example.com'>http://www.example.com</a>";
```

*I remember doing something like this before however, it was not fool proof it kept breaking for complex links.*

Another good idea would be if you have a link such as

> http://example.com/test.php?val1=bla&val2blablabla%20bla%20bla.bl

fix it so it does

```
print "<a href='http://example.com/test.php?val1=bla&val2=bla%20bla%20bla.bla'>";
print "http://example.com/test.php";
print "</a>";
```

This one is just an after thought.. stackoverflow could also probably use this as well :D

Any Ideas

Comment: ooo i see stackoverflow already do the first part.. post the code, u know you want to :D

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Let's look at the requirements. You have some user-supplied plain text, which you want to display with hyperlinked URLs.

1. The "http://" protocol prefix should be optional.
2. Both domains and IP addresses should be accepted.
3. Any valid top-level domain should be accepted, e.g. .aero and .xn--jxalpdlp.
4. Port numbers should be allowed.
5. URLs must be allowed in normal sentence contexts. For instance, in "Visit stackoverflow.com.", the final period is not part of the URL.
6. You probably want to allow "https://" URLs as well, and perhaps others as well.
7. As always when displaying user supplied text in HTML, you want to prevent [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (XSS). Also, you'll want ampersands in URLs to be [correctly escaped](http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp) as &amp;.
8. You probably don't need support for IPv6 addresses.
9. **Edit**: As noted in the comments, support for email-adresses is definitely a plus.
10. **Edit**: Only plain text input is to be supported – HTML tags in the input should not be honoured. (The Bitbucket version supports HTML input.)

**Edit**: Check out [GitHub](https://github.com/kwi-dk/UrlLinker) for the latest version, with support for email addresses, authenticated URLs, URLs in quotes and parentheses, HTML input, as well as an updated TLD list.

Here's my take:

```
<?php
$text = <<<EOD
Here are some URLs:
stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/pregreplace-to-detect-html-php
Here's the answer: http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=42&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&hl=en. What was the question?
A quick look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax is helpful.
There is no place like 127.0.0.1! Except maybe http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/england/surrey/8168892.stm?
Ports: 192.168.0.1:8080, https://example.net:1234/.
Beware of Greeks bringing internationalized top-level domains: xn--hxajbheg2az3al.xn--jxalpdlp.
And remember.Nobody is perfect.

<script>alert('Remember kids: Say no to XSS-attacks! Always HTML escape untrusted input!');</script>
EOD;

$rexProtocol = '(https?://)?';
$rexDomain   = '((?:[-a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}\.)+[-a-zA-Z0-9]{2,63}|(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})';
$rexPort     = '(:[0-9]{1,5})?';
$rexPath     = '(/[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]*?)?';
$rexQuery    = '(\?[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]+?)?';
$rexFragment = '(#[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]+?)?';

// Solution 1:

function callback($match)
{
    // Prepend http:// if no protocol specified
    $completeUrl = $match[1] ? $match[0] : "http://{$match[0]}";

    return '<a href="' . $completeUrl . '">'
        . $match[2] . $match[3] . $match[4] . '</a>';
}

print "<pre>";
print preg_replace_callback("&\\b$rexProtocol$rexDomain$rexPort$rexPath$rexQuery$rexFragment(?=[?.!,;:\"]?(\s|$))&",
    'callback', htmlspecialchars($text));
print "</pre>";
```

- To properly escape < and & characters, I throw the whole text through htmlspecialchars before processing. This is not ideal, as the html escaping can cause misdetection of URL boundaries.
- As demonstrated by the "And remember.Nobody is perfect." line (in which remember.Nobody is treated as an URL, because of the missing space), further checking on valid top-level domains might be in order.

**Edit**: The following code fixes the above two problems, but is quite a bit more verbose since I'm more or less re-implementing `preg_replace_callback` using `preg_match`.

```
// Solution 2:

$validTlds = array_fill_keys(explode(" ", ".aero .asia .biz .cat .com .coop .edu .gov .info .int .jobs .mil .mobi .museum .name .net .org .pro .tel .travel .ac .ad .ae .af .ag .ai .al .am .an .ao .aq .ar .as .at .au .aw .ax .az .ba .bb .bd .be .bf .bg .bh .bi .bj .bm .bn .bo .br .bs .bt .bv .bw .by .bz .ca .cc .cd .cf .cg .ch .ci .ck .cl .cm .cn .co .cr .cu .cv .cx .cy .cz .de .dj .dk .dm .do .dz .ec .ee .eg .er .es .et .eu .fi .fj .fk .fm .fo .fr .ga .gb .gd .ge .gf .gg .gh .gi .gl .gm .gn .gp .gq .gr .gs .gt .gu .gw .gy .hk .hm .hn .hr .ht .hu .id .ie .il .im .in .io .iq .ir .is .it .je .jm .jo .jp .ke .kg .kh .ki .km .kn .kp .kr .kw .ky .kz .la .lb .lc .li .lk .lr .ls .lt .lu .lv .ly .ma .mc .md .me .mg .mh .mk .ml .mm .mn .mo .mp .mq .mr .ms .mt .mu .mv .mw .mx .my .mz .na .nc .ne .nf .ng .ni .nl .no .np .nr .nu .nz .om .pa .pe .pf .pg .ph .pk .pl .pm .pn .pr .ps .pt .pw .py .qa .re .ro .rs .ru .rw .sa .sb .sc .sd .se .sg .sh .si .sj .sk .sl .sm .sn .so .sr .st .su .sv .sy .sz .tc .td .tf .tg .th .tj .tk .tl .tm .tn .to .tp .tr .tt .tv .tw .tz .ua .ug .uk .us .uy .uz .va .vc .ve .vg .vi .vn .vu .wf .ws .ye .yt .yu .za .zm .zw .xn--0zwm56d .xn--11b5bs3a9aj6g .xn--80akhbyknj4f .xn--9t4b11yi5a .xn--deba0ad .xn--g6w251d .xn--hgbk6aj7f53bba .xn--hlcj6aya9esc7a .xn--jxalpdlp .xn--kgbechtv .xn--zckzah .arpa"), true);

$position = 0;
while (preg_match("{\\b$rexProtocol$rexDomain$rexPort$rexPath$rexQuery$rexFragment(?=[?.!,;:\"]?(\s|$))}", $text, &$match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $position))
{
    list($url, $urlPosition) = $match[0];

    // Print the text leading up to the URL.
    print(htmlspecialchars(substr($text, $position, $urlPosition - $position)));

    $domain = $match[2][0];
    $port   = $match[3][0];
    $path   = $match[4][0];

    // Check if the TLD is valid - or that $domain is an IP address.
    $tld = strtolower(strrchr($domain, '.'));
    if (preg_match('{\.[0-9]{1,3}}', $tld) || isset($validTlds[$tld]))
    {
        // Prepend http:// if no protocol specified
        $completeUrl = $match[1][0] ? $url : "http://$url";

        // Print the hyperlink.
        printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', htmlspecialchars($completeUrl), htmlspecialchars("$domain$port$path"));
    }
    else
    {
        // Not a valid URL.
        print(htmlspecialchars($url));
    }

    // Continue text parsing from after the URL.
    $position = $urlPosition + strlen($url);
}

// Print the remainder of the text.
print(htmlspecialchars(substr($text, $position)));
```

Comment: I will try and test your implementation my friend.. And then post your answer to be correct if it works. Will take some time though, cause im not at home. Ps Thanks for releasing it into the public domain :D

Comment: also P.S +1 for the effort :D

Comment: Tried and tested.. Gj, I used Solution 2

Comment: Very helpful. But $rexProtocol is not case sensitive e.g HTTps will not be detected. Can you please tell me how i can achieve it. I want https? and ftp (case insensitive).  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rahul: Simply make the regular expression [case insensitive](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php): In the call to `preg_match`, add an `i` after the final `}` in the regular expression.

Comment: @Søren : Already got fixed. Thanks for the reply. By mistake i was using /i :).

Comment: Few comments:
First, I suggest hosting your code snippets to github.com so we can follow updates on this snippet, suggest changes and report bugs in a structured way.

Comment: Second, htmlEscapeAndLinkUrls() escapes already formatted urls and makes them unclickable. I understand this is a security measurement, but mind that our applications may already have this security measurement in place.

Comment: Third: There is a problem with e-mail addresses. The domain part of the e-mail address is converted, but not the e-mail address as a whole.

Comment: I suggest doing a detection whether the url is enclosed by <a href=''></a>. If so, do nothing.

Comment: @bart: 1) Thanks for the suggestion. I've opted for [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/kwi/urllinker) for various reasons. 2) True, although the question concerned plain text input. The issue of allowing markup in input (whether it be HTML, BBcode or whatever) is much more complex. 3) Good point. The code should handle that; I'll see if I can write something up. 4) Could work. You'd have to prevent users from specifying any other attributes (such as `style`) on the `<a>` tag, as well as prevent non-standard protocols such as `javascript:`.

Comment: An updated version with support for email adresses can be found on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/kwi/urllinker/src).

Comment: This does not work if the plain-text url is wrapped inside some form of parentheses, e.g. [hxxp://www.google.com] won't work, so I changed line 26 to this `$rexUrlLinker = "{\\b$rexUrl(?=[?.!,;:\"\'\|\[\]\(\)\{\}]?(\s|$))}";`

Comment: Would it be easy to extend it when a link is already <a href="http://example.com">example.com</a> that it will be ignored?

Comment: @Laoneo: Unfortunately, safely allowing markup is a rather complex issue (and, I think, outside the scope of this question). In your specific example, you could just use [`strip-tags`](http://php.net/strip-tags) to remove all tags, then use my function to reinstate it, but that obviously only works when the link text matches the link target.

Comment: I have tried the second solution with an url like this "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#starred?compose=141d598cd6e13025" and it does not work properly, any idea?

Comment: @rodi: It's now fixed [on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/kwi/urllinker/commits/bf412ba965f25768387eb5112e59bd33ead5fb5b).

Comment: Thanks for this. It doesn't seem to work with a url like this: http://saloona.co.il/blog/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%93%D7%90%D7%95-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%A4%D7%97%D7%AA-%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A8-%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%95/?ref=popular

Comment: @Guy: _That_ is not a URL. :) Rather, it is an [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier). But feel free to create [an enhancement request on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/kwi/urllinker/issues), and I may look into whether it's a feasible to support.

Comment: Hi, @SørenLøvborg!  I made some upgrades to your code and submitted a Pull Request - hope it works well for you! :) https://bitbucket.org/rinogo/urllinker/overview

Comment: call time pass-by-reference was removed since PHP5.4 and so the third argument to `preg_match` in solution 2 above should be simply `$match` and not `&match`.

Comment: This helped me a great deal. I also added `rel="noFollow"` within the anchor tags.

Comment: what are two problem in solution one ? should not I use it ? (solution one) I tested it and worked correctly.

Comment: @Sajad: The two problems are listed just above the last "Edit", most importantly that `htmlspecialchars` can turn a valid URL into an invalid one. And you should not use either version shown here; use [the up-to-date version on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/kwi/urllinker/). The code here just demonstrates the general idea, while the Bitbucket version contains numerous bugfixes.

Comment: @SørenLøvborg Your regex is wrong, at least for German date notation, as it turns e. g. 20.07.1963 into a clickable link due to the domain portion of the regex. Reluctant reviewers prevented me from editing your post, so please do so yourself by either adding a that note or, even better, fix your regex regarding that issue ASAP. TIA.

Answer (score 17):

You guyz are talking way to advance and complex stuff which is good for some situation, but mostly we need a simple careless solution. How about simply this?

```
preg_replace('/(http[s]{0,1}\:\/\/\S{4,})\s{0,}/ims', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a> ', $text_msg);
```

Just try it and let me know what crazy url it doesnt satisfy.

Comment: Yes... but... why not add the code to make it cut/pasteable?!?! $text_msg=
preg_replace('/(http[s]{0,1}\:\/\/\S{4,})\s{0,}/ims', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a> ', $text_msg);

Comment: Good solution, but if you have HTML in the string, then you might want to replace `\S` with `[^<]`

Comment: `[s]` is too verbose. `{0,1}` is too verbose. `\:` is too verbose. `{0,}` is too verbose.  `ms` is nonsensical.  I do not endorse this answer.

Answer (score 15):

Here is something i found that is tried and tested

```
function make_links_blank($text)
{
  return  preg_replace(
     array(
       '/(?(?=<a[^>]*>.+<\/a>)
             (?:<a[^>]*>.+<\/a>)
             |
             ([^="\']?)((?:https?|ftp|bf2|):\/\/[^<> \n\r]+)
         )/iex',
       '/<a([^>]*)target="?[^"\']+"?/i',
       '/<a([^>]+)>/i',
       '/(^|\s)(www.[^<> \n\r]+)/iex',
       '/(([_A-Za-z0-9-]+)(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@([A-Za-z0-9-]+)
       (\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*)/iex'
       ),
     array(
       "stripslashes((strlen('\\2')>0?'\\1<a href=\"\\2\">\\2</a>\\3':'\\0'))",
       '<a\\1',
       '<a\\1 target="_blank">',
       "stripslashes((strlen('\\2')>0?'\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\">\\2</a>\\3':'\\0'))",
       "stripslashes((strlen('\\2')>0?'<a href=\"mailto:\\0\">\\0</a>':'\\0'))"
       ),
       $text
   );
}
```

It works for me. And it works for emails and URL's, Sorry to answer my own question. :(

But this one is the only that works

Here is the link where i found it : http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/Q_21878567.html

Sry in advance for it being a experts-exchange.

Comment: I'll just note that this solution fails most of the requirements I suggested, namely #1, 2, 3, 5 and 7, but if this meets your requirements, great. Just don't use it on untrusted input, since it performs no HTML escaping. :-)

Comment: You talk about this escaping.. if you could explain what this escaping is, it may make it better for me and who knows someone else, to better understand your answer :D

Comment: To prevent cross site scripting, you must never allow a visitor to add arbitrary HTML code to a page. A simple example is a form handler which simply does a `print($_POST["text"]);`. The simplest (and safest) way to prevent this is to run all user supplied text through `htmlspecialchars()`, which *escapes* HTML tags and entities, effectively turning them into plain text. For this question, you want to allow *some* HTML in the output (namely, link tags), which complicates matters, since we can no longer simply use `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: As stackoverflow does, you could add `rel="nofollow"` to user links

Comment: If the string you're converting is coming from user input stored somewhere like a database, you could prevent XSS by escaping before saving, so you retrieve the escaped text to use with this function

Comment: My newest VPS server has php 7 which outputs Warning: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead ...

Comment: This answer is outdated and cannot longer be used. You cannot incorporate function calls into the replacement argument of a `preg_replace()` (`stripslashes()`).

Answer (score 4):

**Here is the code using Regular Expressions in function**

```
<?php
//Function definations
function MakeUrls($str)
{
$find=array('`((?:https?|ftp)://\S+[[:alnum:]]/?)`si','`((?<!//)(www\.\S+[[:alnum:]]/?))`si');

$replace=array('<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', '<a href="http://$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');

return preg_replace($find,$replace,$str);
}
//Function testing
$str="www.cloudlibz.com";
$str=MakeUrls($str);
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Does this cater for multiple url's in a string?

Comment: Sweet, it caters for multiple url's in a string, you're just missing a "<" at $replace=array('a href

Comment: The `s` pattern modifier is pointless if there is no `.` (any character) in your pattern.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using this function, it works for me

```
function AutoLinkUrls($str,$popup = FALSE){
    if (preg_match_all("#(^|\s|\()((http(s?)://)|(www\.))(\w+[^\s\)\<]+)#i", $str, $matches)){
        $pop = ($popup == TRUE) ? " target=\"_blank\" " : "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches['0']); $i++){
            $period = '';
            if (preg_match("|\.$|", $matches['6'][$i])){
                $period = '.';
                $matches['6'][$i] = substr($matches['6'][$i], 0, -1);
            }
            $str = str_replace($matches['0'][$i],
                    $matches['1'][$i].'<a href="http'.
                    $matches['4'][$i].'://'.
                    $matches['5'][$i].
                    $matches['6'][$i].'"'.$pop.'>http'.
                    $matches['4'][$i].'://'.
                    $matches['5'][$i].
                    $matches['6'][$i].'</a>'.
                    $period, $str);
        }//end for
    }//end if
    return $str;
}//end AutoLinkUrls
```

All credits goes to - http://snipplr.com/view/68586/

Enjoy!

Comment: This one has an issue if your string has comma separated URLs, for example "https://www.google.com, http://www.google.com".  The first URL in this example would end up with a href="https://www.google.com," including the comma.  A URL that ends with a comma is valid, so I guess this is up to the use case if you think it is more likely the string intended the comma as punctuation or as part of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

This RegEx should match any link except for these new 3+ character toplevel domains...

```
{
  \\b
  # Match the leading part (proto://hostname, or just hostname)
  (
    # http://, or https:// leading part
    (https?)://[-\\w]+(\\.\\w[-\\w]*)+
  |
    # or, try to find a hostname with more specific sub-expression
    (?i: [a-z0-9] (?:[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])? \\. )+ # sub domains
    # Now ending .com, etc. For these, require lowercase
    (?-i: com\\b
        | edu\\b
        | biz\\b
        | gov\\b
        | in(?:t|fo)\\b # .int or .info
        | mil\\b
        | net\\b
        | org\\b
        | [a-z][a-z]\\.[a-z][a-z]\\b # two-letter country code
    )
  )

  # Allow an optional port number
  ( : \\d+ )?

  # The rest of the URL is optional, and begins with /
  (
    /
    # The rest are heuristics for what seems to work well
    [^.!,?;"\\'()\[\]\{\}\s\x7F-\\xFF]*
    (
      [.!,?]+ [^.!,?;"\\'()\\[\\]\{\\}\s\\x7F-\\xFF]+
    )*
  )?
}ix
```

It's not written by me, I'm not quite sure where I got it from, sorry that I can give no credit...

Comment: I understand that the above are patterns but im so lost. sry

Answer (score 1):

this should get you email addresses:

```
$string = "bah bah steve@gmail.com foo";
$match = preg_match('/[^\x00-\x20()<>@,;:\\".[\]\x7f-\xff]+(?:\.[^\x00-\x20()<>@,;:\\".[\]\x7f-\xff]+)*\@[^\x00-\x20()<>@,;:\\".[\]\x7f-\xff]+(?:\.[^\x00-\x20()<>@,;:\\".[\]\x7f-\xff]+)+/', $string, $array);
print_r($array);

// outputs:
Array
(
    [0] => steve@gmail.com
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer has been accepted and that this question is quite old, but it can be useful for other people looking for other implementations.

This is a modified version of the code posted by: Angel.King.47 on July 27,09:

```
$text = preg_replace(
 array(
   '/(^|\s|>)(www.[^<> \n\r]+)/iex',
   '/(^|\s|>)([_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,3})?\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\\/[^<> \n\r]+)/iex',
   '/(?(?=<a[^>]*>.+<\/a>)(?:<a[^>]*>.+<\/a>)|([^="\']?)((?:https?):\/\/([^<> \n\r]+)))/iex'
 ),  
 array(
   "stripslashes((strlen('\\2')>0?'\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>&nbsp;\\3':'\\0'))",
   "stripslashes((strlen('\\2')>0?'\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>&nbsp;\\4':'\\0'))",
   "stripslashes((strlen('\\2')>0?'\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\3</a>&nbsp;':'\\0'))",
 ),  
 $text
);
```

Changes:

- I removed rules #2 and #3 (I'm not sure in which situations are useful).
- Removed email parsing as I really don't need it.
- I added one more rule which allows the recognition of URLs in the form: [domain]/*
  (without www). For example: "example.com/faq/" (Multiple tld: domain.{2-3}.{2-4}/)
- When parsing strings starting with "http://", it removes it from the link label.
- Added "target='_blank'" to all links.
- Urls can be specified just after any(?) tag. For example: <b>www.example.com</b>

As "Søren Løvborg" has stated, this function does not escape the URLs. I tried his/her class but it just didn't work as I expected (If you don't trust your users, then try his/her code first).

Comment: `preg_replace()` will not respect any function calls in the replacement string.  The `x` pattern modifier seams needlessly or incorrectly used.  An unescaped dot will mean any character.  Much is wrong about this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in one of the comments above my VPS, which is running php 7, started
emitting warnings **Warning: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead**.
The buffer after the replacement was empty/false.

I have rewritten the code and made some improvements.
If you think that you should be in the author section feel free to edit the comment above the function make_links_blank name.
I am intentionally not using the closing php ?> to avoid inserting whitespace in the output.

```
<?php

class App_Updater_String_Util {
    public static function get_default_link_attribs( $regex_matches = [] ) {
        $t = ' target="_blank" ';
        return $t;
    }

    /**
     * App_Updater_String_Util::set_protocol();
     * @param string $link
     * @return string
     */
    public static function set_protocol( $link ) {
        if ( ! preg_match( '#^https?#si', $link ) ) {
            $link = 'http://' . $link;
        }
        return $link;
    }

/**
     * Goes through text and makes whatever text that look like a link an html link
     * which opens in a new tab/window (by adding target attribute).
     * 
     * Usage: App_Updater_String_Util::make_links_blank( $text );
     * 
     * @param str $text
     * @return str
     * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/replace-urls-in-text-with-html-links
     * @author Angel.King.47 | http://dashee.co.uk
     * @author Svetoslav Marinov (Slavi) | http://orbisius.com
     */
    public static function make_links_blank( $text ) {
        $patterns = [
            '#(?(?=<a[^>]*>.+?<\/a>)
                 (?:<a[^>]*>.+<\/a>)
                 |
                 ([^="\']?)((?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^<> \n\r]+)
             )#six' => function ( $matches ) {
                $r1 = empty( $matches[1] ) ? '' : $matches[1];
                $r2 = empty( $matches[2] ) ? '' : $matches[2];
                $r3 = empty( $matches[3] ) ? '' : $matches[3];

                $r2 = empty( $r2 ) ? '' : App_Updater_String_Util::set_protocol( $r2 );
                $res = ! empty( $r2 ) ? "$r1<a href=\"$r2\">$r2</a>$r3" : $matches[0];
                $res = stripslashes( $res );

                return $res;
             },

            '#(^|\s)((?:https?://|www\.|https?://www\.)[^<>\ \n\r]+)#six' => function ( $matches ) {
                $r1 = empty( $matches[1] ) ? '' : $matches[1];
                $r2 = empty( $matches[2] ) ? '' : $matches[2];
                $r3 = empty( $matches[3] ) ? '' : $matches[3];

                $r2 = ! empty( $r2 ) ? App_Updater_String_Util::set_protocol( $r2 ) : '';
                $res = ! empty( $r2 ) ? "$r1<a href=\"$r2\">$r2</a>$r3" : $matches[0];
                $res = stripslashes( $res );

                return $res;
            },

            // Remove any target attribs (if any)
            '#<a([^>]*)target="?[^"\']+"?#si' => '<a\\1',

            // Put the target attrib
            '#<a([^>]+)>#si' => '<a\\1 target="_blank">',

            // Make emails clickable Mailto links
            '/(([\w\-]+)(\\.[\w\-]+)*@([\w\-]+)
                (\\.[\w\-]+)*)/six' => function ( $matches ) {

                $r = $matches[0];
                $res = ! empty( $r ) ? "<a href=\"mailto:$r\">$r</a>" : $r;
                $res = stripslashes( $res );

                return $res;
            },
        ];

        foreach ( $patterns as $regex => $callback_or_replace ) {
            if ( is_callable( $callback_or_replace ) ) {
                $text = preg_replace_callback( $regex, $callback_or_replace, $text );
            } else {
                $text = preg_replace( $regex, $callback_or_replace, $text );
            }
        }

        return $text;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `s` pattern modifier is pointless if there is no `.` (any character) in your pattern.

Comment: s is for single line

Comment: And only affects dots in a pattern.  It otherwise serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of :

```
<?php
if(preg_match('@^http://(.*)\s|$@g', $textarea_url, $matches)) {
    echo '<a href=http://", $matches[1], '">', $matches[1], '</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: PHP does not respect the `g` modifier. `.*` doesn't seem like a reliable pattern for isolating a url.

Answer (score 0):

**This `class` changes the urls into text and while keeping the home url as it is. I hope this will help and save time for you.Enjoy.**

```
class RegClass 
{ 

     function preg_callback_url($matches) 
     { 
        //var_dump($matches); 
        //Get the matched URL  text <a>text</a>
        $text = $matches[2];
        //Get the matched URL link <a href ="http://www.test.com">text</a>
        $url = $matches[1];

        if($url=='href ="http://www.test.com"'){
         //replace all a tag as it is
         return '<a href='.$url.' rel="nofollow"> '.$text.' </a>'; 

         }else{
         //replace all a tag to text
         return " $text " ;
         }
} 
function ParseText($text){ 

    $text = preg_replace( "/www\./", "http://www.", $text );
        $regex ="/http:\/\/http:\/\/www\./"
    $text = preg_replace( $regex, "http://www.", $text );
        $regex2 = "/https:\/\/http:\/\/www\./";
    $text = preg_replace( $regex2, "https://www.", $text );

        return preg_replace_callback('/<a\s(.+?)>(.+?)<\/a>/is',
                array( &$this,        'preg_callback_url'), $text); 
      } 

} 
$regexp = new RegClass();
echo $regexp->ParseText($text);
```

Comment: This class has used preg_replace _callback function to search and repace URL with text .If you have any error in ParseText Function then just replace the $regex and regex2 with actual patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trust the IANA you can get your current list of offcially supported TLDs in use there like:

```
  $validTLDs = 
explode("\n", file_get_contents('http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt')); //get the official list of valid tlds
  array_shift($validTLDs); //throw away first line containing meta data
  array_pop($validTLDs); //throw away last element which is empty
```

Makes Søren Løvborg's solution #2 a bit less verbose and spares you the hassle of updating the list, nowadays new tlds are thrown out so carelessly ;)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (turned one of the answers into a PHP function)

```
function make_urls_from_text ($text){
   return preg_replace('/(http[s]{0,1}\:\/\/\S{4,})\s{0,}/ims', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1 </a>', $text);
}
```

Comment: There is much to fix with this answer. `[s]` is the same as `s`.  `{0,1}` is more simply written as `?`  Colons do not require escaping.  Using a pattern delimiter other than a forward slash will remove the need to escape forward slashes inside the pattern. `{0,}` is more simply written as `*`.  The `m` modifier doesn't have a `^` or `$` to affect.  The `s` pattern modifier doesn't have a `.` to affect.

Answer (score 0):

This class I created works for my needs, admittedly it does needs some work though;

```
class addLink
{
    public function link($string)
    {
        $expression = "/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,63}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/";
        if(preg_match_all($expression, $string, $matches) == 1)// If the pattern is found then
        {
            $string = preg_replace($expression, '<a href="'.$matches[0][0].'" target="_blank">$1</a>', $string);
        }

        return $string;       
    }
}
```

An example of using this code;

```
include 'PHP/addLink.php';

if(class_exists('addLink')) 
{                  
    $al = new addLink();                  
}
else{
    echo 'Class not found...';
} 

$paragraph = $al->link($paragraph);
```

Comment: `[a-z]{2,4}` is really short for TLDs, have a look at: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db)

Comment: moreover, your regex matches `http://qdj$$$-=`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FuzQ5G/1), not sure it's a valid URL ;)

Comment: I changed the TLD length to 63 as per [RFC 1034](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1034) and updated above...

Comment: I'm currently reading [RFC 1035](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035) to fix my regex pattern matching...

Comment: When you feel like you need `preg_match_all()` followed by `preg_replace()` calls, you probably mean to use `preg_replace_callback()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a variation of the solution posted by **Dharmendra Jadon**, so if you like it up vote his instead!

I just added a parameter to make opening the link in a new window (target="_blank") optional, as I saw this in some of the other solutions and liked the flexibility:

```
function MakeUrls($str, $popup = FALSE)
{
    $find=array('`((?:https?|ftp)://\S+[[:alnum:]]/?)`si','`((?<!//)(www\.\S+[[:alnum:]]/?))`si');

    $replace=array('<a href="$1"' . ($popup ? ' target="_blank"' : '') . '>$1</a>', '<a href="http://$1"' . ($popup ? ' target="_blank"' : '') . '>$1</a>');

    return preg_replace($find,$replace,$str);
}
```

Comment: The `s` pattern modifier is useless if there are no "any character" dots in the pattern.

Comment: This will fail if your link is within quotes (e.g. ```xxxxxxxx "http://www.bbc.com/list"<br>Received yyyyy```) see https://regex101.com/r/puRu94/1

Answer (score -1):

This should get your twitter handle without touching on your email
/(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-*.]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9*]+)/i

Comment: Did you copy my answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304632/regex-for-twitter-username/6351873#6351873 and pasted on to my question, which is not even relevent. A little credit would have at least got you no downvote!

Answer (score -2):

While matching the full url spec is difficult, here's a regular expression that generally does a good job:

```
([\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?)
```

To use this in preg_replace, however, you need to escape it. As so:

```
$pattern = "/([\\w-]+(\\.[\\w-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*?\\.[a-z]{2,6}|(\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})(:\\d{4})?)/";
$replaced_texttext = preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="$0" title="$0">$0</a>', $text);
```

Comment: thats why i hate preg replace... Ima test it out and let you know :D

Comment: http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/england/surrey/8168892.stm does that work for you... Sry you will have to click the link to get full. Stackoverflow is cutting it short

Comment: Funny enough it worked for emails and not url...lol, But failed for emails such as mail@stack.co.uk

Comment: The regular expression had some missing backslashes, which is why it didn't match those URL's properly. Should be fixed now.

Comment: sry to say this.. but nope.. its doing it to only emails and it still have the same problems for domains such as .co.uk, the .uk part gets left out. But its not working for url's at all