# as3 Flex make urls from text clickable

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, url

In an AIR app, I am loading a bunch of arbitrary text via JSON, loading it into an object,  and displaying it via a custom renderer. I would like to have urls be clickable. So I'm sure that this is possible via some crazy regex thing (as I found for php [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/replace-urls-in-text-with-html-links)), but, Flex being flex, I'm astonished that there isn't some builtin functionality for this that I'm just not finding, or, failing that, a library that someone has created to do just this.

(I'm equally astonished that this question hasn't been asked here before. I anticipate being flamed with the link to that)

Failing that, anyone want to help with some crazy regex? ;>

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You could replace the URLs in your text for actual links using the following regex:

```
str = str.replace(/((https?|ftp|telnet|file):((\/\/)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%\/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)/g, "<u><a href='$1'>$1</a></u>");
```

Then set the htmlText on a `Label` or `Text` component and listen for it's `link` event:

```
<mx:Text htmlText="{str}" link="linkHandler(event)"/>
```

Then open the URL on the handler:

```
public function linkHandler(event:TextEvent):void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(event.text), '_blank');
}
```

Except for that regex, I haven't tested this code, but it should work.
Also, [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/textcontrols_04.html#437502) could be of some help to you.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I put down this project for a minute so didn't come back to this tab to thank you in a timely fashion. Will try that and see how it goes. Thank you for comprehending crazy regex for me!

Comment: That was actually a problem I had in my code as well and I fixed it this way, so no problem! :)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that the following RegEx could be much more useful for validating an URL:

`/(((f|ht){1}tp:\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]+)/g`

Comment: Wonderful. Could you explain what makes this regex preferable over the other? (I don't challenge it, I'm just curious. =) One thing I don't understand is why that {1} is necessary. Isn't "one and only one match" the default?