# regex for Twitter username

Tags: python, regex, twitter

Could you provide a regex that match Twitter usernames?

Extra bonus if a Python example is provided.

Comment: What are the constraints on a Twitter username?

Comment: See answer from @rayfranco for spec.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)
```

I've used this as it disregards emails.

Here is a sample tweet:

> @Hello how are @you doing @my_friend, email @000 me @ whats.up@example.com @shahmirj

Matches:

- @Hello
- @you
- @my_friend
- @shahmirj

It will also work for hashtags, I use the same expression with the `@` changed to `#`.

Comment: Very good! Only one correction: hastags and screenNames can have both underscores. I'd add it so in this way the resulting regex is: 
(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]))#([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)

Comment: Well also, the underscore can be at the beginning of the username:
 (?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-\.]))#([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)

Comment: Applying the answer to `'RT @daddy_san: RIGHT IN THE FEELS BRUH` gives only `@daddy` as the answer.

Comment: try `(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)`

Comment: @000 should be catched either as well as screen names with underscore (as mentioned by @backslash17 and @fixxxer). And it will not catch hashtags just by simply raplacing @ with #, since hashtags can contains unicode as well. So the expression for mentions should be `(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-\.]))@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)`

Comment: Could someone suggest a modification to this pattern so that username with . (dot) is also matched but not detecting .(dot) at the end.

Comment: Must limit characters; user names are from 1 to 15 chars; also the user name can start with underscore, checkout twitter username rules [here](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/twitter-username-rules)

Comment: the expression in answer doesn't catch usernames start with and contain underscore. @rokh's version accounts such instances.

Answer (score 21):

If you're talking about the `@username` thing they use on twitter, then you can use this:

```
import re
twitter_username_re = re.compile(r'@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)')
```

To make every instance an HTML link, you could do something like this:

```
my_html_str = twitter_username_re.sub(lambda m: '<a href="http://twitter.com/%s">%s</a>' % (m.group(1), m.group(0)), my_tweet)
```

Comment: Is there any official specification?

Comment: No, but I know that Twitter usernames can contain alphanumerics and underscores, and if they do allow anything else, it's not commonly seen in the wild.

Comment: I love you, but that is not right. Well it is but it will also pick up email addresses, and twitter does not do that.

Comment: Catches email addresses to. Use regex (?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\\.]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+) from Angel.King.47 below.

Answer (score 19):

The regex I use, and that have been tested in multiple contexts :

```py
/(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,15})\b/
```

This is the cleanest way I've found to test and replace Twitter username in strings.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

text = "@RayFranco is answering to @jjconti, this is a real '@username83' but this is an@email.com, and this is a @probablyfaketwitterusername";

ftext = re.sub( r'(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,15})\b', '\\1<a href="http://twitter.com/\\2">\\2</a>', text )

print ftext;
```

This will return me as expected :

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/RayFranco">RayFranco</a> is answering to <a href="http://twitter.com/jjconti">jjconti</a>, this is a real '<a href="http://twitter.com/username83">username83</a>' but this is an@email.com, and this is a @probablyfaketwitterusername
```

Based on [Twitter specs](https://support.twitter.com/articles/101299-why-can-t-i-register-certain-usernames#error) :

> *Your username cannot be longer than 15 characters. Your real name can be longer (20 characters), but usernames are kept shorter for the sake of ease.
>   A username can only contain alphanumeric characters (letters A-Z, numbers 0-9) with the exception of underscores, as noted above. Check to make sure your desired username doesn't contain any symbols, dashes, or spaces.*

Comment: The cleanest. Nice posting of spec.

Comment: thanks, this is great! ...except it incorrectly matches usernames inside medium URLs, e.g. https://medium.com/@p5d12000/xyz. here's a modified version that fixes that: `(^|[^\w@/\!?=&])@(\w{1,15})\b`. (twitter itself is still better - it correctly auto-links just the @-mention in `/@abc`, and the full URL in `https://medium.com/@abc` - but oh well.)

Answer (score 13):

Twitter [recently released](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/02/introducing-open-source-twitter-text.html) to [open source](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text) in various languages including Java, Ruby ([gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/twitter-text)) and Javascript implementations of the code they use for finding user names, hash tags, lists and urls.

It is very regular expression oriented.

Answer (score 2):

The only characters accepted in the form are A-Z, 0-9, and underscore. *Usernames are not case-sensitive*, though, so you could use `r'@(?i)[a-z0-9_]+'` to match everything correctly and also discern between users.

Comment: It doesn't make much of a difference that they are not case-sensitive. `(?i)` refers to your pattern, not the value you capture. It's still up to the program to deal with ABC and Abc as the same value.

Answer (score 2):

This is a method I have used in a project that takes the text attribute of a tweet object and returns the text with both the hashtags and user_mentions linked to their appropriate pages on twitter, complying with the most recent twitter display guidelines

```
def link_tweet(tweet):
"""
This method takes the text attribute from a tweet object and returns it with
user_mentions and hashtags linked
"""
tweet = re.sub(r'(\A|\s)@(\w+)', r'\1@<a href="http://www.twitter.com/\2">\2</a>', str(tweet))
return re.sub(r'(\A|\s)#(\w+)', r'\1#<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23\2">\2</a>', str(tweet))
```

Once you call this method you can pass in the param my_tweet[x].text. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: forgot to mention this ONLY picks up @mentions and #tags, NOT email.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the existing answers and modified it for my use case. (username must be longer then 4 characters)

```
^[A-z0-9_]{5,15}$
```

Rules:

- Your username must be longer than 4 characters.
- Your username must be shorter than 15 characters.
- Your username can only contain letters, numbers and '_'.

Source: https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/twitter-username-rules

Answer (score 1):

Shorter, `/@([\w]+)/` works fine.

Comment: you're missing '_' and characters with accents on that one.
add the equivalent of \p{L} in Python and '_'

Comment: Are they normally included in usernames on Twitter? I don't think he needs to be watching for them. Of course, it would add flexibility I guess

Answer (score 1):

This regex seems to solve Twitter usernames:

```
^@[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15}$
```

Max 15 characters, allows underscores directly after the @, (which Twitter does), and allows all underscores (which, after a quick search, I found that Twitter apparently also does). Excludes email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to match all the `handle`, `@handle` and `twitter.com/handle` formats, this is a variation:

```
import re

match = re.search(r'^(?:.*twitter\.com/|@?)(\w{1,15})(?:$|/.*$)', text)
handle = match.group(1)
```

Explanation, examples and working regex here:
https://regex101.com/r/7KbhqA/3

**Matched**

```
myhandle
@myhandle
@my_handle_2
twitter.com/myhandle
https://twitter.com/myhandle
https://twitter.com/myhandle/randomstuff
```

**Not matched**

```
mysuperhandleistoolong
@mysuperhandleistoolong
https://twitter.com/mysuperhandleistoolong
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex: ^@[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15}$

In python:

```
import re    
pattern = re.compile('^@[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15}$')
pattern.match('@Your_handle')
```

This will check if the string exactly matches the regex.

In a 'practical' setting, you could use it as follows:

```
pattern = re.compile('^@[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15}$')
if pattern.match('@Your_handle'):
    print('Match')
else:
    print('No Match')
```