# How can I find twitter profile links with a regex?

Tags: php, regex, twitter

I want to parse html documents for links to twitter profiles using a regex and preg_match_all() in PHP.  The twitter links are in this form:

```
http(s)://twitter.com/#!/twitter_name
```

I only want to grab links that are purely to the profile page ( eg. nothing after the twitter_name ).

I would like to handle both http and https ( because this is common in these links ).

I would also like to handle //www.twitter.com and //twitter.com ( also common ).

How should I structure my regex?

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
(https?:)*\/\/(www.)*twitter.com\/#!/([A-Za-z0-9_]*)
```

I'm not sure what all characters are valid in a Twitter handle, but I'm assuming 0-9, letters and underscores.

Probably best to run it in case-insensitive mode and get rid of the `A-Z` as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `[(http:|https:)]*` doesn't match what you think it should. It matches `hhhhhhh` or `))::::hpph:|||` for example.

Comment: why kleene star? that would overmatch!

Answer (score 2):

Most general regex (that stops at "/" or space):

```
(https?:)?\/\/(www\.)?twitter.com\/(#!\/)?([^\/ ].)+
```

Comment: How would I modify that to also stop at a double quote ( " )?

Comment: (https?:)?\/\/(www\.)?twitter.com\/(#!\/)?([^\/" ].)+

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
preg_match_all('|https?://(?:www\.)?twitter.com/#!/[a-z0-9_]+|im', $text, $matched)
```

Don't know exacly what characters can be inside twitter username so I assumed [a-z0-9_]+. $matched[1] should be username.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
preg_match_all('~https?://(?:www\.)?twitter.com/#!/([a-z0-9_]+)~im', $html, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` contains the matching user names.

**EDIT**: For more information on what characters can appear in the user name, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6351873/283078) and for more general info see [this Twitter Engineering page](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/02/introducing-open-source-twitter-text.html).