# Regular expression to find usernames in NSString Objective C

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsstring, nsregularexpression

i need to find usernames (like twitters) in strings, for example, if the string is:

"Hello, @username! How are you? And @username2??"

I want to isolate/extract @username and @username2 to colour it with another colour

Do you know how to do it in Objective-C, i found this for Python [regex for Twitter username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304632/regex-for-twitter-username) but it doesn't work for me?

Comment: try ^@username+\d$

Comment: No but, i write @username as an example, it can anyone of twitter usernames.

Comment: regex needs a pattern to identify! Unless all the usernames have a pattern, you can;t use regex to grab them. YOu need to call an api to get twitter usernames.