# How do i use RegEx to find a string at the end of a line after a given pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, string, web, pattern-matching

**Goal is: to remove everything that is not a NAME or ID from a text.**

**Example:**

```
Paula Abdul @PaulaAbdul Dec 25 18:13:07 +0000 (GMT) via XYZ Web Client
( ... Some junk line to remove ... )
Michael Jackson @MichaelJackson Dec 27 16:03:01 +0000 (GMT) via XYZ Web Client
( ... Other stuff to remove / e.g. an empty line)
George Michael @GeorgeMichael Dec 28 19:23:15 +0000 (GMT) via XYZ Web Client
```

**Goal is to extract Name and ID:**

```
Paula Abdul @PaulaAbdul
Michael Jackson @MichaelJackson
George Michael @GeorgeMichael
```

What is the best way to about it?
My idea is:
 1. Select all lines that do not contain "@..."
 2. AND select everything after "@..." to the line end

So far i know:

```
Ignore all Lines with <string>:  ^((?!@<string>).)*$
```

and how can i combine both searches into one?

```
i assume: <pattern1>|<pattern2>
```

*I am using https://atom.io Editor for  my RegExp search.*

Comment: pattern *do not contain "@PaulaAbdul" | select everything after "@PaulaAbdul"* will match the lines with `@MichaelJackson` and `@GeorgeMichael`

Comment: Are you trying to match only `@<value>` ?

Comment: you need to specify WHAT you really expect to find/get at the very end. And you need to tell us what (in your definition) is a Name or ID

Comment: Sorry to be unclear, i edit the description to make it more clear hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution after some research and trial and error.

First i found the code how to identify Twitter IDs: [regex for Twitter username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304632/regex-for-twitter-username)

```
@[\w{1,15}]+
```

This finds any ID that starts with "@" and has between 1-15 characters. 
"\w" stands for "word character", usually [A-Za-z0-9_]. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits.

Through trial and error i found the rest of the pattern:

```
^[\w. ]*(@[\w{1,15}]+)\b
```

This finds any number of words including " " and "." as long as there is a "@" + at least one word-character.

**EXAMPLE SOURCE:**

```
@PaulaAbdul Dec 25 18:13:07 +0000 (GMT) via XYZ Web Client
( ... Some junk line to remove ... )
Clint. @PaulaAbdul Dec 25 18:13:07 +0000 (GMT) via XYZ Web Client
abcdef.abcd 999 ( ... Some junk line to remove ... )
Paula Abdul @PaulaAbdul Dec 25 18:13:07 +0000 (GMT) via XYZ Web Client
Some Words ( ... Some junk line to remove ... )
Michael M. Jackson @MichaelJackson Dec 27 16:03:01 +0000 (GMT) via XYZ Web Client
( ... Other stuff to remove / e.g. an empty line)
George Michael @GeorgeMichael Dec 28 19:23:15 +0000 (GMT) via XYZ Web Client
```

**RESULT:**

```
@PaulaAbdul
Paula Abdul @PaulaAbdul
Michael M. Jackson @MichaelJackson
George Michael @GeorgeMichael
```