# Replace username twitter in python

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, twitter

I have String like below

```
tweet = "thank you guys, for coming my birthday @abcd @defg @hijk , and  @abcd don't forget your promises"
```

How to change that tweet to be

```
tweet = "thank you guys, for coming my birthday USERNAME_TWITTER_1 USERNAME_TWITTER_2 USERNAME_TWITTER_3 , and USERNAME_TWITTER_1 don't forget your promises"
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `id_dispatcher` function:

```
from itertools import count

def id_dispatcher():
    return lambda c=count(1): next(c)
```

Then we can setup a `defaultdict`ionary from the `collections` package:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dc = defaultdict(id_dispatcher())
```

and then use a [regex replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6351873/67579) (see link for the construction of a *Twitter* username regex):

```
import re

re_user = re.compile(r'(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]+)')
outp = re_user.sub(lambda x : 'USERNAME_TWITTER_%s'%dc[x.group(0)],tweet)
```

This produces:

```
>>> re_user.sub(lambda x : 'USERNAME_TWITTER_%s'%dc[x.group(0)],tweet)
"thank you guys, for coming my birthday USERNAME_TWITTER_1 USERNAME_TWITTER_2 USERNAME_TWITTER_3 , and  USERNAME_TWITTER_1 don't forget your promises"
```

Comment: You can make your `id_dispatcher` - `from itertools import count; from collections import defaultdict; dc = defaultdict(lambda c=count(): next(c))`...

Comment: Willem - still slightly over complicating that `id_dispatcher` - at this point it's more simply and understandably written as `def id_dispatcher(): yield from count()`...

Comment: @JonClements: but that is not callable... Then the `next(..)` should be called over that. One can indeed use `id_dispatcher().__next__` but usually that is considered bad coding style.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem oops good point - then we're back to my original comment anyway... :)