# Python Regex Twitter username including @

Tags: python, regex

So I have found this regex:

```
(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)
```

from this question: [regex for Twitter username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304632/regex-for-twitter-username)

But this ignores the actual "@" in the handle when returning. I've tried to edit this to include @ without success. I want to return "@username" instead of "username". How do I edit this regex to include "@"?

Comment: (?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]))(@[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)

Comment: `(?<![\w.-])@[A-Za-z][\w-]+`, see https://regex101.com/r/Pg8NHP/3

Comment: How much experience with regular expressions do you have? Are you sure you want to rely on a tech you seem understand so little?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "returning". Regular expressions don't return anything. Are you talking about matching or maybe capturing groups?

Comment: I don't have much experience but your suggestion works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to put `@` inside the capturing group you are returning. However, the pattern is highly cryptic and can be greatly simplified.

```
(?<![\w.-])@[A-Za-z][\w-]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pg8NHP/3/)

**Details**

- `(?<![\w.-])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a word char, or `.` or `-`
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[A-Za-z]` - an ASCII letter
- `[\w-]+` - 1 or more word chars or hyphens.

In Python 3, compile the pattern with `re.ASCII` flag to make `\w` only match ASCII letters and digits.