# RegEx for twitter usernames

Tags: python, regex

I need some help with regex for usernames which start with "@" and following rules:

1. Username includes only \w symbols.
2. Match if string has any non word character except "@", e.g.

   - Match @username in `@username!&?()*^`
   - But don't match in `@username@username`, `@username!@username` or
     `@username!%^@` (if string has at least one more "@").
3. Don't match if string has any symbols before "@", e.g.

   - Don't match @username in `not@username` or `!@username`.

For now i have:

```
(?<!\w)@(\w{4,15})\b(?!@)
```

Which excludes only \w symbols before and "@" if it stands only after username.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53616269/15521392) help?

Comment: nope, it matches these examples: first @username in @username@username and both in @username!@username

Comment: Try `^@\w+\b(?!.*@)`, see https://regex101.com/r/R1W0k0/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assert a whitespace boundary to the left, and assert not @ in the line to the right.

```
(?<!\S)@(\w{4,15})\b(?![^@\n]*@)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `@` Match literally
- `(\w{4,15})\b` Capture 4-15 word chars followed by a word boundary
- `(?![^@\n]*@)` Assert not optional repetitions of any char except @ or a newline to the right followed by @

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HEOpfU/1)