# Trying to pull a twitter handle from a text file

Tags: python-3.x, wing-ide

I am trying to extract a set of alpha numeric characters from a text file.

below would be some lines in the file. I want to extract the '@' as well as anything that follows.

im trying to pull @bob from a file.
this is a @line in the @file
@bob is a wierdo

the below code is what I have so far.

```
def getAllPeople(fileName):
    #give empty list
    allPeople=[]
    #open TweetsFile.txt
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f1:
        lines=f1.readlines()
        #split all words into strings
        for word in lines:
            char = word.split("@")
            print(char)
    #close the file
    f1.close()
```

What I am trying to get is;
['@bob','@line','@file', '@bob']

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex for Twitter username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304632/regex-for-twitter-username)

Comment: Could also just split the string by white space, then filter the resulting array of strings to only have the ones containing the @ symbol. I like the regex idea though

Comment: I thought of that but the .readlines puts it in a list, and you cant .split a list

Comment: just `.read()` @Russ? or `.read().replace('\n', '')` or `' '.join(f.readlines())`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html), take Andrew's suggestion

```
mentions = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('@'), tweet.split()))
```

otherwise, see the marked duplicate.

---

```
mentions = [w for w in tweet.split() if w.startswith('@')]
```

since you apparently can not use `filter` or `lambda`.

Comment: I cant use the filter and lambda stuff

Comment: why can you not use `filter` and `lambda`

Comment: I doubt any decent instructor would be upset at using language features especially ones that do not require other imports. I added another solution anyway