# php: how to regex replace the following strings?

Tags: php, regex

would like to replace all occurence of, double quote included

`"http://somebunchofchar"`

to

`"link"`

I came up with `preg_replace("/\"http:\/\/.\"/i", "\"link\"", $string);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/replace-urls-in-text-with-html-links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an asterisk and question mark after dot

`preg_replace("/\"http:\/\/.*?\"/i", "\"link\"", $string);`

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = preg_replace('#"http://.+"#', '"link"', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
preg_replace('~"http://[^"]*"~i', '"link"', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look here:
http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=1&categoryId=2&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
how to match an URL with the correct pattern; than use preg_replace with the particular regexp pattern ;-) (you can add those quotes at the start and end to the pattern yourself quite easily) :-)