# replace same url in text with regex

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, str-replace

I am using the following code to add links to urls in text...

```
   if (preg_match_all("#((http(s?)://)|www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.])(\w+[^\s\)\<]+)#i", $str, $matches))
   {
         ?><pre><?php
         print_r($matches);
         ?></pre><?php
         for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++)
         {
             $url = $matches[0][$i];
             $parsed = parse_url($url);

             $prefix = '';
             if (!isset($parsed["scheme"])){
                $prefix = 'http://';
             }


             $url = $prefix.$url;

             $replace = '<a href="'.$url.'" class="auto_link_color">'.$matches[0][$i].'</a>';

             $str = str_replace($matches[0][$i], '<a href="'.$prefix.$matches[0][$i].'" class="auto_link_color">'.$matches[0][$i].'</a>', $str);
         }
     }
```

the problem comes when i enter twice the same url in the text at any place..

for example.

```
google.com text text google.com
```

it will add a link on the first one and then search for google.com which is inside the link and try to add again in there..

how can i make sure it will add the links separately without problems?

Comment: You need to match the complete link.

Comment: You could have a look at my answer to [Converting text to link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410655/converting-text-to-link-php-regex-issue/9412798#9412798).

Comment: @rodneyrehm i tried your code but even if i type simple text it will try to add http:// at first

Comment: well, yes, of course. A link without protocol (http://) will have a browser request it relative to the current domain. This is not what you want, so my replace function fixes that for you.

Comment: it seems to work now, another problem is that it doesnt work with text like google.com google.fr ... how can your regex be edited to work with urls that didnt have www or http at first?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback) to reliably work on individual matches.