# how to replace youtube url in text?

Tags: php

I have following text

```
"I made this video on my birthday. All of my friends are here in party. Click play to video the video
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3j6avmJU48&feature=g-all-xit "
```

What i want is to replace this above url to

```
"I made this video on my birthday. All of my friends are here in party. Click play to video the video

      <iframe width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/G3j6avmJU48" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> "
```

I know we can get youtube video id from above url in following script

```
     preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+(?=\?)|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be/)[^&\n]+#", $word, $matches);


        $youtube_id = $matches[0];
```

But I dont know how to replace url

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3j6avmJU48&feature=g-all-xit
```

to

```
  <iframe width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/G3j6avmJU48" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Please help Thanks

Comment: This is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/replace-urls-in-text-with-html-links)

Comment: how its duplicate when it has to get the id from url and replace the url with iframe tag? the link which is described is just a normal link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preg_replace function ([see PHP preg_replace() Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php))

**Edit :**

Using preg_replace is as follows : you use parentheses () to wrap what you want to capture in the regex (first parameter) and then you use $n (n beeing the parenthese order in the regex) in the second parameter to get what you captured.

In your case you should have something like this :

```
$text = "I made this video on my birthday. All of my friends are here in party. Click play to video the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3j6avmJU48&feature=g-all-xit";

$replaced = preg_replace('#http://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v=(\w+)[^\s]+#i','<iframe width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',$text);
```

For more advanced usage and examples see the documentation link I provided you before.

Hope this helps you more.

**Edit 2 :**
The regex was wrong, I fixed it.

Comment: If i would know how to use preg_place it would not be asking for help. :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample code to achieve it, based on @Matt comment:

```
<?php
$text = "I made this video on my birthday. All of my friends are here in party. Click play to video the video
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3j6avmJU48&feature=g-all-xit ";

$rexProtocol = '(https?://)?';
$rexDomain   = '(www\.youtube\.com)';
$rexPort     = '(:[0-9]{1,5})?';
$rexPath     = '(/[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]*?)?';
$rexQuery    = '(\?[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]+?)?';
$rexFragment = '(#[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]+?)?';

function callback($match)
{
    $completeUrl = $match[1] ? $match[0] : "http://{$match[0]}";
    $videoId = array ();
    preg_match ("|\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9]*)|", $match[5], $videoId);

    return '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $videoId[1] . '" width="853" height="480"></iframe>';
}
print preg_replace_callback("&\\b$rexProtocol$rexDomain$rexPort$rexPath$rexQuery$rexFragment(?=[?.!,;:\"]?(\s|$))&", 'callback', htmlspecialchars($text));

?>
```