# PHP Convert all urls into html links

Tags: php, regex, function, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace URLs in text with HTML links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/replace-urls-in-text-with-html-links)

I'm passing the string variable which contains multiple urls, through function below to get same thing only with proper HTML links.

```
public function convertUrlsToLinks($text){
    return preg_replace( '@(?<![.*">])\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|[a-z]\.)[-A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$]@i', '<a href="\0" target="_blank">\0</a>', $text );
}
```

It doesn't work at all. What am I missing?

**Code must skip existing links, `<img>`'s `src` values (or something like that.)**

Answer (score 0):

assuming you already have an html document, I limited the recognition of URLs to

- not start with an "
- start with http or www

i came up with a solution like this:

```
$string = 'lorem ipsum www.foo.bar dolor sit <a href="http://fail.org">http://fail.org</a><img src="www.foo.bar"> amet http://abc.de.fg.com?bar=baz';
$rx = '%[^"](?P<link>(?:https?://|www\.)(?:[-_a-z0-9]+\.)+(?:[a-z]{2,4}|museum/?)(?:[-_a-z0-9/]+)?(?:\?[-_a-z0-9+\%=&]+)?(?!</a)(\W|$))%ui';
echo preg_replace_callback($rx, function($matches) {
    return '<a href="'.$matches['link'].'">'.$matches['link'].'</a>';
}, $string).PHP_EOL;
```

the output string is

```
lorem ipsum<a href="www.foo.bar ">www.foo.bar </a>dolor sit <a href="http://fail.org">http://fail.org</a><img src="www.foo.bar"> amet<a href="http://abc.de.fg.com?bar=baz">http://abc.de.fg.com?bar=baz</a>
```

The regex *should* work as intendet, an example string of yours could help