# Finetune Regex to skip tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Code must skip existing links, `<img>`'s src values (or something like that)

```
public function convertUrlsToLinks($text){
    return preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.-]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
}
```

Can't figure out, what I need to modify in this function?

Comment: Unless you need to use regular expression, you can use. **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**, and get everything with an `<a>` tag as plaintext.

Comment: (possible) duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11958415/1596455

Answer (score 0):

Add a small part to your regex that checks if your regex isn't 'inside' a tag. So it should be

```
     <tag>HERE</tag>
```

and not

```
     <tag src="HERE"></tag>.
```

Since a url will always be INSIDE the html tag it should work if you finetune your regex to this use. I'm not a pro with regex' so can't help you more than this, but I think this should get you in the right direction.