# Regex syntax issue

Tags: php, regex, function, url, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finetune Regex to skip tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958903/finetune-regex-to-skip-tags)

Currently my function looks like this. It converts plain text URLs into HTML links.

```
function UrlsToLinks($text){
    return preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.-]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
}
```

But there are some problems. What I'm trying to do is skip existing links, the `src` attribute in `<img>` tags, etc..  Can't figure out what I need to modify in this function.

Comment: What is the string you are trying to parse?

Comment: Your desired functionality is painfully difficult, if not impossible, to achieve using regular expressions, much less a single regular expression. You really should be using an HTML parser, looking for links only within the text content of HTML nodes.

Comment: What you need to do is use an HTML parser to extract the text nodes and only run *them* through the above function. Trying to modify it so that it will ignore bits and pieces of HTML will bring down the wrath of Tony the Pony and we will all burn in the firey depths. Either that or your application will be insecure and unreliable, one of the two.

Comment: @Rocket html markup, images, urls as plain text inside

Comment: @epic_syntax: see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11958415/1596455

Answer (score 1):

This would work, assuming that the URLs we want to replace are not already inside a tag.

```
function UrlsToLinks($text){
    $matches = array();
    $strippedText = strip_tags($text);

    preg_match_all('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.-]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', $strippedText, $matches);

    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {       
        if (filter_var($match, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            $text = str_replace($match, '<a href="'.$match.'" target="_blank">'.$match.'</a>', $text);
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
```