# Showing url/hyperlink database fetched data

Tags: php, database, echo, fetch

I have a question about a well known problem: the messages of my users contain hyperlinks to other area's of my website. I fetch data from the database to show the last message a user has posted on his profile. This works, but I can't see the hyperlinks. I just see them as plain text. How can I make these things hyperlinks as they should be?

I use this for example:

```
$lastpost = execute_scalar("SELECT message FROM messages where messages.user='$who' Order by date desc");
```

@Prasath Albert here you go:

```
    $message = preg_replace("'\look here: (.*)\)'Ui","(look here: <a href=\"haha.php?&q=\\1\">\\1</a>)",$message);
```

Comment: put the code that generate the hyperlink for further investigation..

Comment: How are the links presented in the database? As regular HTML (<a href=") or for example as BB-code ([url]http://url)?

Comment: How can you see this? Let me say this: people can click on a button, that fetches a javascript with inputfields. Their, they can link to an topic in my website. This is in the back-end with http:// but on the site, there is no http:// or whatsoever. It just says "spoon" or "football" for example and those are then links.

@Prasath Albert: I have put the code as you asked

Answer (score 0):

use this links

[Replace URLs in text with HTML links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/replace-urls-in-text-with-html-links)

http://zenverse.net/php-function-to-auto-convert-url-into-hyperlink/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yogesh, but it did not work. It is still plain text. I used the code from your second link.

Let me be clear: I have functions that produce internal hyperlinks without the WWw or HTTP:// before it.