# How to fetch MYSQL data as hyperlink?

Tags: mysql, hyperlink, fetch, plaintext

On my site, people can link to topics with buttons I made. Those buttons are putting out a `(look: http://....)` or `(look: (link without http://)`  on the textarea and when they submit it, the hyperlink shows in their post. That is very nice, but if I fetch this data to show them their last posts, I don't get the `hyperlink`, but just the plain text. So (look: http://....) does not lead to a link...

I have seen in phpmyadmin that it is stored as plain text, so I can understand that, but how can I make those things hyperlinks and the rest of the text (the no-links) just plain?

Comment: Do you want to expose the username and password of your db to the users?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/replace-urls-in-text-with-html-links

Comment: @TJ what do you mean precisely?

Comment: @Sibu: Thanks mate, I will read that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `htmlentities` to convert those hyperlinks before saving them in your database. You can then use `html_entity_decode` when getting the data from the database.

Comment: @Sibu: nope, didn't work at all... And I will look onto htmlentities, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please take into account the aforementioned comments about security issues. You have to sanitize data the user inputed data before you further process the data.

To answer your question. Store the links in a separate column of your table. Then fletch your links to the user via PHP - I guess you are using MySQL in combination with PHP - like you do with the posts. If you want to create a link you need to use the anchor HTML tag. E.g. `<a href="http://yourlink">Name link</a>`.