# Building <a></a> when user enter an url

Tags: php, url

I have a input field which user enters something. Basically when user enter an url which start with **http://**  **https//** or **www.** i want to store it like `<a href="user's words..">user's words...</a>`

I'm working with php and mysql. I think replace function is for it. But when I read about it, this function only working on all string as far as I know.

For example:

**input:** 
Hi, how are you? Please check this link : http:// www.google.com and enjoy.

**output should like below:**
Hi, how are you? Please check this link : [http://www.google.com](http://www.google.com.tr) and enjoy.

Comment: What have you tried? Show some of the code. I would use `preg_replace` or something like it

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/replace-urls-in-text-with-html-links

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been asked a million time before and a proper solution can be found at the Related Questions to the bottom right of this page.

Comment: I doubt you really want to store it like that. You may want to display it like that, but storing it probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (I don't test this code)

```
$output = preg_replace("#(http://|www\.)(.*) #Uis",'<a href="$1$2">$1$2</a>', $input);
```

Comment: What about https URLs?

Comment: it is only a help. I don't want to give all the code ;)
This is a good site (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) for preg_replace.

Comment: looks op just copied from other place (_(I don't test this code)_) :D

Comment: haha no it's my code :P