# Replace a text using php

Tags: php, str-replace, php-5.3, php-5.4

I have a problem,I want to replace a text with str_replace using php.I have a textarea in tinymce editor with text and I loaded image there.The image is saved in database ../image.png now I want to replace ../ with storage.com but don't replace and I don't understand where is the problem

```
$text         = $this->input->post('text', TRUE);
$text         = addslashes($text);
$text         = str_replace('../','http://storage.com/',$text);
```

Help me please.

Comment: What your getting as value for `$text` before replacing.

Comment: you want to replace it in the database or in the php only?

Comment: before insert in database I want to replace $text with http://storage.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/replace-urls-in-text-with-html-links/16509122#16509122

Comment: Jenz I got: text text text ../

Comment: Before running `str_replace` do `var_dump($text)` to make sure it has what you expect in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your replacement code seems to work fine. The first line of your code probably returns something else than what you expect

```
$text         = '../image.png';
echo $text . "\n";
$text         = addslashes($text);
$text         = str_replace('../','http://storage.com/',$text);
echo $text . "\n";
```

This code outputs

```
../image.png
http://storage.com/image.png
```